# NodeJS Decrypt Data Corrupt Original Data

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes

I use AES-266-CBC to encrypt data:

```
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex');
const encrypt = (text: string): string => {
  log('encrypt');

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', ENCRYPTION_KEY, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');

  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return encrypted;
};

const decrypt = (text: string): string => {
  log('decrypt');

  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', ENCRYPTION_KEY, iv);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8');
  decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
  return decrypted;
};
```

And everything works perfectly that means if i use this:

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
  user: 'MHF',
  info: {
    age: 23,
    family: 'HF'
  }
});

const encrypted = encrypt(data);
console.log('encrypted: %s', encrypted);

const decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);
console.log('decrypted: %s', decrypted);
```

The problem is that when i send my encrypted string by a post request http like this:

```
POST {{baseUrl}}/v1/user-register
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encrypted: AES

{"payLoad": "3f1d1584b0e1976ccea311b5fbe0b2aee1034198a582a3b8bcc773c175e91bb0ceda6b9fb88aff11a892fa7adb83d432"}
```

I have a decrypted data by some incorrect chars like this:
*'r!!(h\x7F!o#L\x19\x10~\x7F"jnfo":{"age":23,"family":"HF"}}'*

Why When i do a post request by encrypted data i have this result?
What is this: 'r!!(h\x7F!o#L\x19\x10~\x7F"j'?

Comment: Encryption and decryption require the same IV. Looks like you are using different IVs. Usually during encryption a random IV is generated and sent to the recipient with the ciphertext (typically concatenated).

Comment: @Topaco
Yes i send the same IV to both functions:  

const iv = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex');

Comment: @mh f: I'm sorry but you used the same **function** that generates a **random** iv to encrypt and decrypt, so on decrypt side it will be a **different** iv than that one used on encryption side - thats the point Topaco made.

Comment: @Topaco
@ Michael Fehr
You are right
It was my big mistake.
Thanks anyway to both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Topaco and @Michael Fehr
It was my big mistake about generating and using IV